# Custom std::shared_ptr<T> implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

I'd like to get a few pointers about my code.
I know that shared_ptr is up and running, and I'm reinventing the wheel but you can't say no to the school assignment.

```
template <typename T> class SharedPointer;

template <typename T>
void swap(SharedPointer<T> &lhs, SharedPointer<T> &rhs)
{
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}

template <typename T>
class SharedPointer {
    friend void swap<T>(SharedPointer &lhs, SharedPointer &rhs);

public:
    SharedPointer(): use_c(new std::size_t(0)), p(nullptr), deleter(Deleter()) { }
    SharedPointer(T *ptr): p(ptr), use_c(new std::size_t(1)), deleter(Deleter()) { }
    SharedPointer(T *ptr, const std::function<void(*)> &del):
            p(ptr), use_c(new std::size_t(1)), deleter(del) { }
    SharedPointer(const SharedPointer &rhs): 
            use_c(rhs.use_c), p(rhs.p), deleter(rhs.deleter) { ++*use_c; }

    SharedPointer(SharedPointer &&) noexcept;
    SharedPointer& operator=(const SharedPointer &);
    SharedPointer& operator=(SharedPointer &&) noexcept;
    ~SharedPointer() { free(); }

    std::size_t use_count() { return *use_c; }

    bool unique() const { return *use_c == 1; }

    operator bool() const { return p != nullptr; }

    void reset() noexcept { free(); use_c = new std::size_t(0); };
    void reset(T*);
    void reset(T*, const std::function<void(T*)>&);

    void swap(SharedPointer<T>&);

    T* get() const { return p; }

    T& operator*() const { return *p; }
    T* operator->() const { return &*p; }

private:
    std::size_t *use_c;
    T *p;
    std::function<void(T*)> deleter;

    void free();
};

template <typename T>
SharedPointer<T>::SharedPointer(SharedPointer &&rhs) noexcept:
        use_c(rhs.use_c), p(rhs.p), deleter(std::move(rhs.deleter))
{
    rhs.use_c = new std::size_t(0);
    rhs.p = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
SharedPointer<T> &SharedPointer<T>::operator=(const SharedPointer &rhs)
{
    ++*rhs.use_c;
    free();
    this->use_c = rhs.use_c;
    this->p = rhs.p;
    this->deleter = rhs.deleter;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
SharedPointer<T> &SharedPointer<T>::operator=(SharedPointer &&rhs) noexcept
{
    swap(rhs);
    rhs.free();
    rhs.use_c = new std::size_t(0);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void SharedPointer<T>::reset(T *rhs)
{
    if (p != rhs) {
        free();
        p = rhs;
        use_c = new std::size_t(1);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void SharedPointer<T>::reset(T *rhs, const std::function<void(T *)> &del)
{
    if (p != rhs) {
        reset(rhs);
        deleter = del;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void SharedPointer<T>::swap(SharedPointer<T> &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(this->use_c, rhs.use_c);
    swap(this->p, rhs.p);
    swap(this->deleter, rhs.deleter);
}

template <typename T>
void SharedPointer<T>::free()
{
    if (p && --*use_c == 0) {
        deleter(p);
        delete use_c;
    } else if (!p) {
        delete use_c;
    }
    use_c = nullptr;
    p = nullptr;
}
```

I've yet to add here some non-member operators, but I guess that's trivial and it's no use to litter this post so much.
I've tried to test it here and there and it looks like it works but I'm unsure about copy-and-swap and few other things.
It uses this functor class as the default deleter, if anyone is wondering what's that about.

```
class Deleter {
public:
    template <typename T> void operator()(T *p) const;
};

template <typename T> void Deleter::operator()(T *p) const
{
    delete p;
}
```

So basically I'd like to ask your help with the copy-and-swap idiom - if this implementation is correct and if it's needed at all and the overall coding style.

Answer (score 3):

Nice first post!

There are things that `std::unique_ptr` provides which are absent here, notably the aliasing constructor (so you can own the containing object of what's referenced) and weak pointers (so cached values don't cause unwanted object retention) but otherwise, this is pretty good.

## Omissions

I had a couple of compilation errors, because it's missing `#include <functional>`.  Also, the deleter ought to have a specialization for array types (which need `delete[] p;` instead of `delete p;`).

## Naming

On naming, I'd probably choose something like `release()` for what you've called `free()` - but that's probably just because of half a lifetime writing C.

## Copy and swap

You mention the copy-and-swap idiom; this is how you'd use it for your assignment operator:

```
template<typename T>
SharedPointer<T>& SharedPointer<T>::operator=(SharedPointer rhs)
{
    swap(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Notice that we pass `rhs` *by value*, which means we're getting the copy constructor to do all the work for us.  Having swapped, `rhs` has our old value, which is then destructed at the end of the function, so we don't have to duplicate the work of the constructor.

## Move-assignment

Move assignment doesn't need to reset `rhs` - just perform the swap, and expect the moved-from value to be destructed soon:

```
template <typename T>
SharedPointer<T> &SharedPointer<T>::operator=(SharedPointer &&rhs) noexcept
{
    swap(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

## Swap

The `swap` function doesn't need to be a friend, as it uses only the public interface of the shared pointer.

## Use default arguments to simplify

You can reduce the number of constructors, like this:

```
SharedPointer(T *ptr = nullptr,
              const std::function<void(*)> &del = Deleter())
    : p(ptr),
      use_c(new std::size_t(ptr!=nullptr)),
      deleter(del)
{ }
```

This is also true for the `reset()` method.

## Reset should change deleter

The condition in `reset()` skips changing the deleter if there's no change to the pointer.  But we might be calling `reset()` for exactly that purpose.  Also, if a null pointer is passed as the new value, it's treated the same as a non-null pointer.  Both of these problems can be avoided by using `swap()` and default arguments (to re-use our constructor and destructor):

```
    // declaration
    void reset(T* = nullptr, const std::function<void(T*)>& = Deleter());

template <typename T>
void SharedPointer<T>::reset(T *rhs, const std::function<void(T*)>& del)
{
    swap(SharedPointer(rhs, del));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a thorough review. I've skipped the includes because there was too much code for a post, but it indeed uses <functional> and the deleter is that fuctor class that is shown at the end of the post.

Comment: It's okay. I've just reformatted it according to your advice and it looks much better. Wrote down that use_c member initialisation too, looks mighty smart

Answer (score 1):

Let's first take a look at your data-structures.

1. Your shared control-block consists only of a strong reference-count, so you have no support for `WeakPointer`s, which are somewhat important for manually breaking cycles.
2. Your deleter is stored as a `std::function<void(T*)>` directly in the `SharedPointer` itself, meaning that:

   - Copying/moving a `SharedPointer` gets more expensive, potentially involving allocating dynamic memory for the `std::function`.
   - You have to have the correct pointer on hand for passing to the `std::function` to free the managed object. So, no pointing to a sub-object, dependent object, or base class subobject. That's fairly restrictive.
3. Nothing much to be said about the pointer to the pointee itself.

How should it be organized instead?

```
class SharedPointerControlblock {
    virtual void destroy() noexcept = 0; // destroys pointee
    std::size_t cWeak = 1; // weak reference count. Destroy cb if 0
    std::size_t cStrong = 1; // strong reference count. Destroy pointee if 0
protected:
    virtual ~SharedPointerControlblock() = default;
public:
    // fastAddRef() tryAddRef() release() weakAddRef() weakRelease()
};
```

Create `final` derived classes as needed.

4. There's no reason to define `swap(SP&, SP&)` before the class is defined. Doing so just leads to more typing and worse reading.
5. `swap` should be `noexcept`.
6. There's no reason to make a function just using the public interface a `friend`. Really.
7. A default-constructed SP should not allocate any memory at all.
8. The deleter used should be a template-argument of the ctor used instead of provided via `std::function` for efficiency and versatility. Actually, better make it an allocator than a deleter, and use the added possibilities.
9. The best you can do with your move-ctor is removing every trace of its existence, and rely on the copy-ctor. That has a lower chance of throwing an exception and won't abort the program if it does. The only problem with the copy-ctor is that it must copy a `std::function` and is thus not `noexcept`.
10. Remember that a moved-from object can have any arbitrary valid state. Don't waste any effort to guarantee more.

```
constexpr SharedPointer() noexcept : use_c(), p() {}
SharedPointer(SharedPointer&& o) noexcept : SharedPointer() { swap(o); }
SharedPointer(const SharedPointer& o) use_c(o.use_c), p(o.p), deleter(o.deleter) { if(use_c( ++*use_c; }
SharedPointer& operator=(SharedPointer&& o) noexcept { swap(o); return *this; }
SharedPointer& operator=(SharedPointer o) { swap(o); return *this; }
```

11. `&*p` Hm, what? Why not simply `p` as it's a raw pointer already.
12. Your `reset()` should not concern itself with whether the new pointer is the old pointer. If it is, and not `nullptr`, that's programmer error.
13. `reset()` should not ever leave the object in a halfway state, ever.
14. You should only ever delete the use-count if it's `0`, and not make its decrementing dependent on `p`.

Comment: On point 12, we could follow `std::shared_ptr::reset(T *ptr)` which says (CPP Reference) "**If the object pointed to by ptr is already owned, the function results in undefined behaviour.**" - with no escape clause for the existing owner being `this`.  So I'd say that if the new pointer is the old pointer, that *must be* programmer error, always.

Answer (score 0):

### Things that are broken

#### Must always take ownership

When you create a smart pointer it must **always** take ownership if things go wrong. If the constructor fails in some way then you must delete the passed object (becuase the destructor is not run if the constructor does not complete).

The problem with this is:

```
SharedPointer(T *ptr)
    : p(ptr)
    , use_c(new std::size_t(1))
    , deleter(Deleter())
{ }
```

You call `new`. Unfortunately this can fail with an exception. If this happens the pointer is leaked. Once the user has called your constructor they expect you to have ownership. So you must delete that pointer if new throws an exception.

```
SharedPointer(T *ptr)
try {
    : p(ptr)
    , use_c(new std::size_t(1))
    , deleter(Deleter())
{ }
} catch(...) {
    delete ptr;
    throw;
}
```

#### Accidentally creating a shared pointer without knowing it.

If you have a function/method that has a shared pointer as a parameter. Then the compiler will auto convert a pointer into shared pointer before the call. Thus taking ownership of the pointer. When the function exits the shared pointer is destroyed and your pointer deleted. If you did not realize that the function was taking a shared pointer then your pointer is destroyed.

```
void myCode(SharedPointer<int> data) {
    // Do stuff with int
}

int main()
{
    int* x = new int(5);
    myCode(x);  // will delete the pointer x
                // did you expect that?
                // The compiler will not complain.
    *x += 2; 
}
```

#### Assignment operator not exception safe

```
template <typename T>
SharedPointer<T> &SharedPointer<T>::operator=(const SharedPointer &rhs)
{
    ++*rhs.use_c;

    // What happens if free() throws an exception?
    free();
    // Well the current object is fine (it will be correctly destroyed).
    // But the object represented by `rhs` has a incorrect count that will
    // will never reach zero.


    this->use_c = rhs.use_c;
    this->p = rhs.p;
    this->deleter = rhs.deleter;
    return *this;
}
```

The assignment operator should work in three distinct phases.

```
1) Allocate resources into temp objects  (dangerous might throw)
2) Do an exception safe swap of the temp object and the current objets state.
3) Release resources (now in temp object). Again dangerous but the object
   is in a consistent state.
```

The classic implementation of these three steps is the `Copy and Swap Idiom`.

```
 {
     Shared<object>  tmp(rhs);   // make a copy into a temp object.
     swap(tmp, *this);           // swap the temp object and this.
 }
 // Let the tmp object go out of scope and destroy its content.
 // This was the original content of this.
```

### Things that are missing

#### Initializing with `nullptr`

You can't initialize your smart pointer with `nullptr`. It may not seem necessary but a lot of the template code initializes with a zero object.It would not surprise me that there is a `nullptr` initialization for pointer types in there somewhere.

```
SharedPointer<int>    x(nullptr);   // Fails to compile
SharedPointer<int>    y(reinterpret_cast<int*>(nullptr)); // Seems a bit long winded.
```

#### Derived Types

One of the big features in C++ is derived types.

```
Animal* a = new Cat;
```

Being able to assigning Cat(s) to Animals(s) is normal operation.

```
Cat*    c = new Cat;
Animal* a = c;        // Should work the same.
```

Or more likely

```
void makeNoise(Animal* a) { a->makeNoise();}

// Later.
Cat*    c = new Cat;
makeNoise(c);
```

If we translate this directly into your shared pointer it will no longer compiler.

```
SharedPointer<Animal> a(new Cat);   // OK this works
```

Being able to assigning Cat(s) to Animals(s) is normal operation.

```
SharedPointer<Cat>    c(new Cat);
SharedPointer<Animal> a(c);        // Should work the same.
                                   // But this is a compiler error.
```

Or more likely

```
void makeNoise(SharedPointer<Animal> a) { a->makeNoise();}

// Later.
SharedPointer<Cat>    c(new Cat);
makeNoise(c);                           // Now fails to compile.
```

### Things that look strange

#### Testing if a pointer is already stored.

```
template <typename T>
void SharedPointer<T>::reset(T *rhs)
{
    if (p != rhs) {
        free();
        p = rhs;
        use_c = new std::size_t(1);
    }
}
```

When you give a pointer to a shared pointer you are asking it to take ownership. If it has ownership you should not have any copies of the pointer running around your code (otherwise what is the point of the shared pointer).

So it seems that this is a logical error in your code. If somebody assigns a pointer to a shared pointer that happens to be the same as the already contained pointer there is something seriously wrong with the users code. I would prefer this test did not exist or if it does exist it throws an exception to indicate the enormity of the problem.

The second reset

```
template <typename T>
void SharedPointer<T>::reset(T *rhs, const std::function<void(T *)> &del)
{
    if (p != rhs) {
        reset(rhs);
        deleter = del;
    }
}
```

Since this is a call to the previous `reset()` that already tests for assignment of self there is no need to call here. Simply call `reset(rhs)` and the child version will test for self assignment.

#### Prefer not to use `this->`

```
template <typename T>
void SharedPointer<T>::swap(SharedPointer<T> &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(this->use_c, rhs.use_c);
    swap(this->p, rhs.p);
    swap(this->deleter, rhs.deleter);
}
```

There is no need for `this->` in this context.

Unlike Java it is very unusual to use `this->` in C++ code. Using it also leads to errors that compilers can not detect. The only reason to use `this->`is to distinguish a local variable from a member variable that has the same name. This is called shadowing. The problem is that the compiler can not tell if you meant the local variable or the member so there is no way to automatically detect when you accidentally forget to use `this->`.

On the other hand the compiler can easily detect shadowed variables and generate a warning. A compiler warning is a logical error in your code that you should fix (your code compiles with zero warnings when you add -Wall -Wextra?).

Anyway, not using shadowed variables makes your code easier to read and understand and you will never accidentally assign to the wrong variable (as they have completely different names).